# Can elasticsearch with node, update only a certain field without rewrite?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

My document has a field that looks like this:

```
_source:
...
"produto_tags" : [
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "1623153806",
              "tags" : []
            },
            {
             "id_produto_cor" : "875623985732",
             "tags": []
            },
            {...}
...
```

I need to insert on this field another Object without rewrite the entire **produto_tags**

```
data to be inserted:
             {
             "id_produto_cor" : "312411",
             "tags": []
            },
```

and my final document will looks like this:

```
_source:
...
"produto_tags" : [
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "1623153806",
              "tags" : []
            },
            {
             "id_produto_cor" : "875623985732",
             "tags": []
            },
            {
             "id_produto_cor" : "312411",
             "tags": []
            }
]
```

Im using NODE js, I`m using this but it rewrites what I put :

```
 const query = { 
      doc: {
        nome_relatorio: nome_relatorio,
        produto_tags: produto_tags,
        referencia_tags: referencia_tags,
      }
    };
```

```
    return await esClient.update({
        index: indexName,
        body: query,
        id: id,
        method: 'post',
        type: typeDoc,  
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. You can use [update_by_query api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/docs-update-by-query.html)**

```
POST <index_name>/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.produto_tags.add(params.product)",
    "params": {
      "product": {
        "product_id": "1004600287",
        "tags": []
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {} --> select the document
  }
}
```

**2. Update api**

```
POST <index_name>/_update/<doc_id>
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.produto_tags.add(params.product)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "product": {
        "product_id": "11",
        "tags": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```